# Asp.net: pass client information

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm building a website with asp.net mvc and there is some data that I need to consult with every browser request. This contains the clients date and its latitude/longitude. This way we can update the users (using a PDA) location.

If we assume that I already have the latitude & longitude, how can I pass it to the webserver with every browser request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP headers (and cookies in particular) look like an appropriate place.